# Org-babel and ESS: Problem with exporting ANSI code to pdf

Tags: org-babel, ess

I am having some issues with Org mode Babel exporting output with ANSI characters.

When I don't specify a session (example 1), everything is OK.

When I specify a specific session, the code is garbled (example 2).

Any suggestions?

## Example 1

```
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both
  library(readr)
  read_csv("data/gormsey.csv")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
# A tibble: 2,422 × 7
   Sample_No Date       Sample_Point Suburb         Measure        Result Units 
       <dbl> <date>     <chr>        <chr>          <chr>           <dbl> <chr> 
 1    603998 2069-01-01 ME_15385     Merton         Chlorine Total  0.18  mg/L  
 2    603431 2069-01-01 ME_15385     Merton         E. coli         0     Orgs/…
 3    638433 2069-01-01 ME_12236     Merton         Chlorine Total  0.59  mg/L  
 4    617355 2069-01-01 ME_12236     Merton         E. coli         0     Orgs/…
 5    663362 2069-01-03 SN_11009     Snake's Canyon Chlorine Total  0.08  mg/L  
 6    618816 2069-01-03 SN_11009     Snake's Canyon Turbidity       0.2   NTU   
 7    620121 2069-01-03 SN_11009     Snake's Canyon E. coli         0     Orgs/…
 8    627981 2069-01-03 ME_15385     Merton         E. coli         0     Orgs/…
 9    618060 2069-01-03 ME_15385     Merton         Turbidity       0.2   NTU   
10    665782 2069-01-03 ME_15385     Merton         Chlorine Total  0.025 mg/L  
# … with 2,412 more rows
#+end_example
```

## Example 2

```
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both :session R
  library(readr)
  read_csv("data/gormsey.csv")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example

[1mindexing[0m [34mgormsey.csv[0m [=====================================] [32m10.28GB/s[0m, eta: [36m 0s[0m
                                                                                                                   
[1mRows: [22m[34m2422[39m [1mColumns: [22m[34m7[39m
[36m──[39m [1mColumn specification[22m [36m─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[39m
[1mDelimiter:[22m ","
[31mchr[39m  (4): Sample_Point, Suburb, Measure, Units
[32mdbl[39m  (2): Sample_No, Result
[34mdate[39m (1): Date

[36mℹ[39m Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
[36mℹ[39m Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
[90m# A tibble: 2,422 × 7[39m
   Sample_No Date       Sample_Point Suburb         Measure        Result Units 
       [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m [3m[90m<date>[39m[23m     [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m        [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m          [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m           [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m [3m[90m<chr>[39m[23m 
[90m 1[39m    [4m6[24m[4m0[24m[4m3[24m998 2069-01-01 ME_15385     Merton         Chlorine Total  0.18  mg/L  
[90m 2[39m    [4m6[24m[4m0[24m[4m3[24m431 2069-01-01 ME_15385     Merton         E. coli         0     Orgs/…
[90m 3[39m    [4m6[24m[4m3[24m[4m8[24m433 2069-01-01 ME_12236     Merton         Chlorine Total  0.59  mg/L  
[90m 4[39m    [4m6[24m[4m1[24m[4m7[24m355 2069-01-01 ME_12236     Merton         E. coli         0     Orgs/…
[90m 5[39m    [4m6[24m[4m6[24m[4m3[24m362 2069-01-03 SN_11009     Snake's Canyon Chlorine Total  0.08  mg/L  
[90m 6[39m    [4m6[24m[4m1[24m[4m8[24m816 2069-01-03 SN_11009     Snake's Canyon Turbidity       0.2   NTU   
[90m 7[39m    [4m6[24m[4m2[24m[4m0[24m121 2069-01-03 SN_11009     Snake's Canyon E. coli         0     Orgs/…
[90m 8[39m    [4m6[24m[4m2[24m[4m7[24m981 2069-01-03 ME_15385     Merton         E. coli         0     Orgs/…
[90m 9[39m    [4m6[24m[4m1[24m[4m8[24m060 2069-01-03 ME_15385     Merton         Turbidity       0.2   NTU   
[90m10[39m    [4m6[24m[4m6[24m[4m5[24m782 2069-01-03 ME_15385     Merton         Chlorine Total  0.025 mg/L  
[90m# … with 2,412 more rows[39m
#+end_example
```

Comment: These are terminal control escape sequences which R apparently emits if it thinks its output is going to a terminal. You will have to convince it not to do that, but that's an R question, not an Emacs question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way `tibbles` are coloured in interactive sessions. One solution is to turn of the colouring in R, which you can do with the `options` function:

```
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both :session R
  options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)
  library(readr)
  read_csv("data/gormsey.csv")
#+end_src
```

This should apply in all subsequent code blocks in the same session, so you only need the `options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)` line in the first one.

[More discussion on github.](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/395)

You can modify `orgmode` to automatically strip out the ansi escape codes when evaluating an R session. This isn't a user option, it requires over-writing the function `org-babel-R-evaluate-session`:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'org
  ;; I use progn because in my actual config I over-write a 
  ;; few other unrelated functions not included here.
  '(progn 
     (defun org-babel-R-evaluate-session
         (session body result-type result-params column-names-p row-names-p)
       "Evaluate BODY in SESSION.
If RESULT-TYPE equals `output' then return standard output as a
string.  If RESULT-TYPE equals `value' then return the value of the
last statement in BODY, as elisp."
       (cl-case result-type
         (value
          (with-temp-buffer
            (insert (org-babel-chomp body))
            (let ((ess-local-process-name
               (process-name (get-buffer-process session)))
              (ess-eval-visibly-p nil))
          (ess-eval-buffer nil)))
          (let ((tmp-file (org-babel-temp-file "R-")))
            (org-babel-comint-eval-invisibly-and-wait-for-file
         session tmp-file
         (format org-babel-R-write-object-command
             (if row-names-p "TRUE" "FALSE")
             (if column-names-p
                 (if row-names-p "NA" "TRUE")
               "FALSE")
             ".Last.value" (org-babel-process-file-name tmp-file 'noquote)))
            (org-babel-R-process-value-result
         (org-babel-result-cond result-params
           (with-temp-buffer
             (insert-file-contents tmp-file)
             (org-babel-chomp (buffer-string) "\n"))
           (org-babel-import-elisp-from-file tmp-file '(16)))
         column-names-p)))
         (output
          ;; strip ansi-color-control-seq-regexp from output!!
          (replace-regexp-in-string
           ansi-color-control-seq-regexp ""
           (mapconcat
            'org-babel-chomp
            (butlast
             (delq nil
               (mapcar
                (lambda (line) (when (> (length line) 0) line))
                (mapcar
                 (lambda (line) ;; cleanup extra prompts left in output
               (if (string-match
                    "^\\([>+.]\\([ ][>.+]\\)*[ ]\\)"
                    (car (split-string line "\n")))
                   (substring line (match-end 1))
                 line))
                 (org-babel-comint-with-output (session org-babel-R-eoe-output)
               (insert (mapconcat 'org-babel-chomp
                          (list body org-babel-R-eoe-indicator)
                          "\n"))
               (inferior-ess-send-input)))))) "\n")))))
     ))
```

Related discussion on [orgmode help list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-03/msg00338.html).

## Update:

Here's the reproducible example posted by OP on another site, along with the results when I run it on my computer. My solution solves the issue for me, although it doesn't work for OP. The main difference I see is that I'm using a more recent Emacs (built from source), but I'm not sure if that explains the difference.

```
#+title: Org Babel and tibbles

Start from ~emacs -Q~ and run each of the following blocks in order.

#+begin_src elisp
  (require 'package)

  (setq package-load-list
    '((ess t)
      (julia-mode t)
      (poly-R)
      (markdown-mode)))

  (package-initialize)

  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((emacs-lisp . t)
     (R . t)
     (org .t)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:


* Default session
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both
  library(tibble)
  as_tibble(iris)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
# A tibble: 150 × 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
#+end_example

* Defined session
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both :session R
  library(tibble)
  as_tibble(iris)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
[90m# A tibble: 150 × 5[39m
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m       [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m        [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m       [3m[90m<dbl>[39m[23m [3m[90m<fct>[39m[23m  
[90m 1[39m          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
[90m 2[39m          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
[90m 3[39m          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
[90m 4[39m          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
[90m 5[39m          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
[90m 6[39m          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
[90m 7[39m          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
[90m 8[39m          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
[90m 9[39m          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
[90m10[39m          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
[90m# … with 140 more rows[39m
#+end_example

* Partial workaround
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both :session S
 library(tibble)
 options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)
 as_tibble(iris)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
# A tibble: 150 × 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
#+end_example

* Versions
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(emacs-version)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: GNU Emacs 29.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0)
:  of 2021-12-13

#+begin_src R :results output
  R.Version()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "1.3"

$year
[1] "2022"

$month
[1] "03"

$day
[1] "10"

$`svn rev`
[1] "81868"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)"

$nickname
[1] "One Push-Up"

#+end_example

#+begin_src R :colnames yes
  installed.packages()[, c(1, 3)]
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Package            |    Version |
|--------------------+------------|
| abind              |      1.4-5 |
| ade4               |     1.7-18 |
| adegenet           |      2.1.5 |
| adegraphics        |     1.0-16 |
| adehabitatHR       |     0.4.19 |
| adehabitatLT       |     0.3.25 |
| adehabitatMA       |     0.3.14 |
| adephylo           |     1.1-11 |
| adespatial         |     0.3-14 |
| AER                |      1.2-9 |
| akima              |    0.6-2.3 |
| alphahull          |        2.4 |
| ape                |      5.6-2 |
| askpass            |        1.1 |
| assertthat         |      0.2.1 |
| backports          |      1.4.1 |
| base64enc          |      0.1-3 |
| base64url          |        1.4 |
| bbmle              |     1.0.24 |
| bdsmatrix          |      1.3-4 |
| BH                 |   1.78.0-0 |
| Biobase            |     2.54.0 |
| BiocGenerics       |     0.40.0 |
| BiocManager        |    1.30.16 |
| BiocVersion        |     3.14.0 |
| biomod2            |      3.5.1 |
| bit                |      4.0.4 |
| bit64              |      4.0.5 |
| bitops             |      1.0-7 |
| blob               |      1.2.2 |
| blockCV            |      2.1.4 |
| blogdown           |        1.9 |
| bookdown           |       0.25 |
| boot               |     1.3-28 |
| brew               |      1.0-7 |
| brio               |      1.1.3 |
| broom              |     0.7.12 |
| bslib              |      0.3.1 |
| cachem             |      1.0.6 |
| calibrate          |      1.7.7 |
| CalibratR          |      0.1.2 |
| callr              |      3.7.0 |
| car                |     3.0-12 |
| carData            |      3.0-5 |
| caret              |     6.0-91 |
| caTools            |     1.18.2 |
| cellranger         |      1.1.0 |
| checkmate          |      2.0.0 |
| CircStats          |      0.2-6 |
| class              |     7.3-20 |
| classInt           |      0.4-3 |
| cli                |      3.2.0 |
| clipr              |      0.8.0 |
| clisymbols         |      1.2.0 |
| cluster            |      2.1.3 |
| coda               |     0.19-4 |
| codetools          |     0.2-18 |
| colorspace         |      2.0-3 |
| combinat           |      0.0-8 |
| commonmark         |      1.8.0 |
| conditionz         |      0.1.0 |
| conquer            |      1.3.0 |
| corrplot           |       0.92 |
| covr               |      3.5.1 |
| cowplot            |      1.1.1 |
| cpp11              |      0.4.2 |
| crayon             |      1.5.1 |
| credentials        |      1.3.2 |
| crosstalk          |      1.2.0 |
| crul               |      1.2.0 |
| curl               |      4.3.2 |
| cyclocomp          |      1.1.0 |
| cytolib            |      2.6.1 |
| data.table         |     1.14.2 |
| DBI                |      1.1.2 |
| DBItest            |      1.7.2 |
| dbplyr             |      2.1.1 |
| deldir             |      1.0-6 |
| dendextend         |     1.15.2 |
| DEoptimR           |     1.0-10 |
| desc               |      1.4.1 |
| devtools           |      2.4.3 |
| dichromat          |      2.0-0 |
| diffobj            |      0.3.5 |
| digest             |     0.6.29 |
| dismo              |      1.3-5 |
| doParallel         |     1.0.17 |
| doSNOW             |     1.0.20 |
| dotCall64          |      1.0-1 |
| downlit            |      0.4.0 |
| dplyr              |      1.0.8 |
| drc                |      3.0-1 |
| DT                 |       0.22 |
| dtplyr             |      1.2.1 |
| dygraphs           |    1.1.1.6 |
| dynlm              |      0.3-6 |
| e1071              |      1.7-9 |
| earth              |      5.3.1 |
| ecodist            |      2.0.7 |
| ecospat            |      3.2.1 |
| ellipse            |      0.4.2 |
| ellipsis           |      0.3.2 |
| ENMeval            |      2.0.3 |
| ENMTools           |      1.0.6 |
| evaluate           |       0.15 |
| exactextractr      |      0.8.0 |
| expm               |    0.999-6 |
| FactoMineR         |        2.4 |
| fansi              |      1.0.3 |
| farver             |      2.1.0 |
| fastcluster        |      1.2.3 |
| fastmap            |      1.1.0 |
| fastshap           |      0.0.7 |
| fauxpas            |      0.5.0 |
| feather            |      0.3.5 |
| fields             |       13.3 |
| filehash           |      2.4-3 |
| fitdistrplus       |      1.1-8 |
| flashClust         |     1.01-2 |
| flowCore           |      2.6.0 |
| flowPloidyData     |     1.20.0 |
| FNN                |      1.1.3 |
| foghorn            |      1.4.2 |
| fontawesome        |      0.2.2 |
| forcats            |      0.5.1 |
| foreach            |      1.5.2 |
| foreign            |     0.8-82 |
| formatR            |       1.11 |
| Formula            |      1.2-4 |
| fs                 |      1.5.2 |
| future             |     1.24.0 |
| future.apply       |      1.8.1 |
| gap                |    1.2.3-1 |
| gapminder          |      0.3.0 |
| gargle             |      1.2.0 |
| gaston             |      1.5.7 |
| gbm                |      2.1.8 |
| gdata              |     2.18.0 |
| gdistance          |      1.3-6 |
| generics           |      0.1.2 |
| genetics           |  1.3.8.1.3 |
| geojsonsf          |      2.0.2 |
| geometries         |      0.2.0 |
| geometry           |      0.4.5 |
| geosphere          |     1.5-14 |
| gert               |      1.6.0 |
| GGally             |      2.1.2 |
| ggforce            |      0.3.3 |
| ggplot2            |      3.3.5 |
| ggpubr             |      0.4.0 |
| ggrepel            |      0.9.1 |
| ggsci              |        2.9 |
| ggsignif           |      0.6.3 |
| gh                 |      1.3.0 |
| gifski             |    1.4.3-1 |
| gitcreds           |      0.1.1 |
| glmnet             |      4.1-3 |
| globals            |     0.14.0 |
| glue               |      1.6.2 |
| gmailr             |      1.0.1 |
| gmodels            |     2.18.1 |
| goftest            |      1.2-3 |
| googledrive        |      2.0.0 |
| googlesheets4      |      1.0.0 |
| gower              |      1.0.0 |
| gridExtra          |        2.3 |
| gridGraphics       |      0.5-1 |
| gtable             |      0.3.0 |
| gtools             |      3.9.2 |
| gWidgets           |     0.0-54 |
| gWidgets2          |      1.0-9 |
| gWidgetstcltk      |   0.0-55.1 |
| hardhat            |      0.2.0 |
| haven              |      2.4.3 |
| here               |      1.0.1 |
| hexbin             |     1.28.2 |
| hierfstat          |     0.5-10 |
| highr              |        0.9 |
| hitandrun          |      0.5-5 |
| Hmisc              |      4.6-0 |
| hms                |      1.1.1 |
| htmlTable          |      2.4.0 |
| htmltools          |      0.5.2 |
| htmlwidgets        |      1.5.4 |
| httpcode           |      0.3.0 |
| httpuv             |      1.6.5 |
| httr               |      1.4.2 |
| hunspell           |      3.0.1 |
| HydroMe            |      2.0-1 |
| hypervolume        |      3.0.2 |
| ids                |      1.0.1 |
| igraph             |     1.2.11 |
| ini                |      0.3.1 |
| ipred              |     0.9-12 |
| isoband            |      0.2.5 |
| iterators          |     1.0.14 |
| jpeg               |      0.1-9 |
| jquerylib          |      0.1.4 |
| jsonify            |      1.2.1 |
| jsonlite           |      1.8.0 |
| JuliaCall          |     0.17.4 |
| kernlab            |     0.9-29 |
| KernSmooth         |    2.23-20 |
| knitr              |       1.38 |
| ks                 |     1.13.4 |
| labeling           |      0.4.2 |
| later              |      1.3.0 |
| lattice            |    0.20-45 |
| latticeExtra       |     0.6-29 |
| lava               |     1.6.10 |
| lazyeval           |      0.2.2 |
| leafem             |      0.1.6 |
| leaflet            |      2.1.1 |
| leaflet.providers  |      1.9.0 |
| leafpop            |      0.1.0 |
| leafsync           |      0.1.0 |
| leaps              |        3.1 |
| LearnBayes         |     2.15.1 |
| lhs                |      1.1.5 |
| lifecycle          |      1.0.1 |
| linprog            |      0.9-4 |
| lintr              |      2.0.1 |
| listenv            |      0.8.0 |
| littler            |     0.3.15 |
| lme4               |     1.1-28 |
| lmtest             |     0.9-40 |
| lpSolve            |     5.6.15 |
| lubridate          |      1.8.0 |
| lwgeom             |      0.2-8 |
| magic              |      1.6-0 |
| magick             |      2.7.3 |
| magrittr           |      2.0.3 |
| mapproj            |      1.2.8 |
| maps               |      3.4.0 |
| maptools           |      1.1-3 |
| maptree            |      1.4-7 |
| mapview            |     2.10.0 |
| markdown           |        1.1 |
| MASS               |     7.3-56 |
| Matrix             |      1.4-1 |
| MatrixModels       |      0.5-0 |
| matrixStats        |     0.61.0 |
| maxnet             |      0.1.4 |
| mclust             |      5.4.9 |
| mda                |      0.5-2 |
| measurements       |      1.4.0 |
| memoise            |      2.0.1 |
| mgcv               |     1.8-40 |
| microbenchmark     |      1.4.9 |
| mime               |       0.12 |
| miniUI             |    0.1.1.1 |
| minpack.lm         |      1.2-1 |
| minqa              |      1.2.4 |
| misc3d             |      0.9-1 |
| mmod               |      1.3.3 |
| mnormt             |      2.0.2 |
| mockery            |      0.4.3 |
| ModelMetrics       |    1.2.2.2 |
| modelr             |      0.1.8 |
| multcomp           |     1.4-18 |
| multicool          |     0.1-12 |
| munsell            |      0.5.0 |
| mvtnorm            |      1.1-3 |
| nabor              |      0.5.0 |
| natserv            |      1.0.0 |
| ncdf4              |       1.19 |
| NISTnls            |     0.9-13 |
| NISTunits          |      1.0.1 |
| nlme               |    3.1-157 |
| nloptr             |      2.0.0 |
| nls2               |        0.2 |
| nlstools           |      2.0-0 |
| nnet               |     7.3-17 |
| NRAIA              |     0.9-12 |
| numDeriv           | 2016.8-1.1 |
| oai                |      0.3.2 |
| odbc               |      1.3.3 |
| openssl            |      2.0.0 |
| packrat            |      0.7.0 |
| palmerpenguins     |      0.1.0 |
| parallelly         |     1.30.0 |
| parsedate          |      1.3.0 |
| pbapply            |      1.5-0 |
| pbkrtest           |      0.5.1 |
| pcaPP              |     1.9-74 |
| pdist              |        1.2 |
| pdp                |      0.7.0 |
| pegas              |        1.1 |
| permute            |      0.9-7 |
| phylobase          |     0.8.10 |
| pillar             |      1.7.0 |
| pingr              |      2.0.1 |
| pixmap             |     0.4-12 |
| pkgbuild           |      1.3.1 |
| pkgconfig          |      2.0.3 |
| pkgdown            |      2.0.2 |
| pkgload            |      1.2.4 |
| plogr              |      0.2.0 |
| plot3D             |        1.4 |
| plotly             |     4.10.0 |
| plotmo             |      3.6.1 |
| plotrix            |      3.8-2 |
| plyr               |      1.8.7 |
| png                |      0.1-7 |
| poibin             |        1.5 |
| polspline          |     1.1.19 |
| polyclip           |     1.10-0 |
| polynom            |      1.4-0 |
| polysat            |      1.7-6 |
| pool               |      0.1.6 |
| PopGenReport       |      3.0.4 |
| poppr              |      2.9.3 |
| pracma             |      2.3.8 |
| praise             |      1.0.0 |
| PresenceAbsence    |     1.1.10 |
| prettyunits        |      1.1.1 |
| pROC               |     1.18.0 |
| processx           |      3.5.3 |
| prodlim            | 2019.11.13 |
| progress           |      1.2.2 |
| progressr          |     0.10.0 |
| promises           |    1.2.0.1 |
| proto              |      1.0.0 |
| proxy              |     0.4-26 |
| ps                 |      1.6.0 |
| psych              |      2.2.3 |
| purrr              |      0.3.4 |
| qpdf               |        1.1 |
| quantreg           |       5.88 |
| R.cache            |     0.15.0 |
| R.methodsS3        |      1.8.1 |
| R.oo               |     1.24.0 |
| R.utils            |     2.11.0 |
| R6                 |      2.5.1 |
| ragg               |      1.2.2 |
| randomForest       |      4.7-1 |
| rangeModelMetadata |      0.1.4 |
| ranger             |     0.13.1 |
| rapidjsonr         |      1.2.0 |
| rappdirs           |      0.3.3 |
| raster             |     3.5-15 |
| rasterVis          |     0.51.2 |
| rbison             |      1.0.0 |
| rcdd               |        1.5 |
| rcmdcheck          |      1.4.0 |
| RColorBrewer       |      1.1-2 |
| Rcpp               |    1.0.8.3 |
| RcppArmadillo      | 0.10.8.1.0 |
| RcppEigen          |  0.3.3.9.1 |
| RcppParallel       |      5.1.5 |
| RcppProgress       |      0.4.2 |
| RcppTOML           |      0.1.7 |
| readr              |      2.1.2 |
| readxl             |      1.4.0 |
| rebird             |      1.3.0 |
| recipes            |      0.2.0 |
| rematch            |      1.0.1 |
| rematch2           |      2.1.2 |
| remotes            |      2.4.2 |
| reprex             |      2.0.1 |
| reshape            |      0.8.8 |
| reshape2           |      1.4.4 |
| ResourceSelection  |      0.3-5 |
| reticulate         |       1.24 |
| rex                |      1.2.1 |
| rgbif              |      3.7.1 |
| rgdal              |     1.5-29 |
| rgeos              |      0.5-9 |
| rgl                |    0.108.3 |
| RgoogleMaps        |    1.4.5.3 |
| Rhdf5lib           |     1.16.0 |
| rhub               |      1.1.1 |
| ridigbio           |      0.3.5 |
| rJava              |      1.0-6 |
| rlang              |      1.0.2 |
| rmarkdown          |       2.13 |
| rms                |      6.2-0 |
| rncl               |      0.8.6 |
| RNeXML             |      2.4.6 |
| robustbase         |     0.93-9 |
| roxygen2           |      7.1.2 |
| rpart              |     4.1.16 |
| RPostgres          |      1.4.3 |
| RPostgreSQL        |      0.7-3 |
| rprojroot          |      2.0.2 |
| RProtoBufLib       |      2.6.0 |
| rrcov              |      1.6-2 |
| rsconnect          |     0.8.25 |
| RSQLite            |     2.2.11 |
| rstatix            |      0.7.0 |
| RStoolbox          |      0.3.0 |
| rstudioapi         |       0.13 |
| rticles            |       0.23 |
| rversions          |      2.1.1 |
| rvertnet           |      0.8.2 |
| rvest              |      1.0.2 |
| rworldmap          |      1.3-6 |
| s2                 |      1.0.7 |
| S4Vectors          |     0.32.3 |
| sandwich           |      3.0-1 |
| sass               |      0.4.1 |
| satellite          |      1.0.4 |
| scales             |      1.1.1 |
| scatterplot3d      |     0.3-41 |
| segmented          |      1.4-1 |
| selectr            |      0.4-2 |
| seqinr             |      4.2-8 |
| servr              |       0.24 |
| sessioninfo        |      1.2.2 |
| sf                 |      1.0-7 |
| sfheaders          |      0.4.0 |
| sgeostat           |     1.0-27 |
| shape              |      1.4.6 |
| shiny              |      1.7.1 |
| showtext           |      0.9-5 |
| showtextdb         |        3.0 |
| sloop              |      1.0.1 |
| snow               |      0.4-4 |
| snowfall           |   1.84-6.1 |
| sourcetools        |      0.1.7 |
| sp                 |      1.4-6 |
| spam               |      2.8-0 |
| SparseM            |       1.81 |
| spatial            |     7.3-15 |
| spatialreg         |      1.2-1 |
| spatstat           |      2.3-3 |
| spatstat.core      |      2.4-0 |
| spatstat.data      |      2.1-4 |
| spatstat.geom      |      2.4-0 |
| spatstat.linnet    |      2.3-2 |
| spatstat.random    |      2.2-0 |
| spatstat.sparse    |      2.1-0 |
| spatstat.utils     |      2.3-0 |
| spData             |      2.0.1 |
| spdep              |      1.2-3 |
| spelling           |        2.2 |
| splancs            |    2.01-42 |
| spocc              |      1.2.0 |
| spThin             |      0.2.0 |
| SQUAREM            |     2021.1 |
| stars              |      0.5-5 |
| stringi            |      1.7.6 |
| stringr            |      1.4.0 |
| strucchange        |      1.5-2 |
| styler             |      1.7.0 |
| survival           |      3.3-1 |
| svglite            |      2.1.0 |
| sys                |        3.4 |
| sysfonts           |      0.8.8 |
| systemfonts        |      1.0.4 |
| targets            |     0.11.0 |
| TeachingDemos      |       2.12 |
| tensor             |        1.5 |
| terra              |     1.5-21 |
| testit             |       0.13 |
| testthat           |      3.1.3 |
| textshaping        |      0.3.6 |
| TH.data            |      1.1-0 |
| tibble             |      3.1.6 |
| tidyr              |      1.2.0 |
| tidyselect         |      1.1.2 |
| tidyverse          |      1.3.1 |
| tikzDevice         |   0.12.3.1 |
| timeDate           |   3043.102 |
| tinytest           |      1.3.1 |
| tinytex            |       0.38 |
| tmap               |      3.3-3 |
| tmaptools          |      3.1-1 |
| tmvnsim            |      1.0-2 |
| triebeard          |      0.3.0 |
| tripack            |    1.3-9.1 |
| tufte              |       0.12 |
| tweenr             |      1.0.2 |
| tzdb               |      0.3.0 |
| udunits2           |   0.13.2.1 |
| units              |      0.8-0 |
| urltools           |      1.7.3 |
| usdm               |     1.1-18 |
| usethis            |      2.1.5 |
| utf8               |      1.2.2 |
| uuid               |      1.0-4 |
| vcr                |      1.0.2 |
| vctrs              |      0.4.0 |
| vegan              |      2.5-7 |
| vegan3d            |      1.1-2 |
| vip                |      0.3.2 |
| viridis            |      0.6.2 |
| viridisLite        |      0.4.0 |
| virtualspecies     |      1.5.1 |
| vroom              |      1.5.7 |
| waldo              |      0.4.0 |
| webmockr           |      0.8.0 |
| webshot            |      0.5.2 |
| wellknown          |      0.7.4 |
| whisker            |        0.4 |
| whoami             |      1.3.0 |
| widgetframe        |      0.3.1 |
| withr              |      2.5.0 |
| wk                 |      0.6.0 |
| xfun               |        0.3 |
| XML                |   3.99-0.9 |
| xml2               |      1.3.3 |
| xmlparsedata       |      1.0.5 |
| xopen              |      1.0.0 |
| xtable             |      1.8-4 |
| xts                |     0.12.1 |
| yaml               |      2.3.5 |
| zip                |      2.2.0 |
| zoo                |      1.8-9 |
| base               |      4.1.3 |
| compiler           |      4.1.3 |
| datasets           |      4.1.3 |
| graphics           |      4.1.3 |
| grDevices          |      4.1.3 |
| grid               |      4.1.3 |
| methods            |      4.1.3 |
| parallel           |      4.1.3 |
| splines            |      4.1.3 |
| stats              |      4.1.3 |
| stats4             |      4.1.3 |
| tcltk              |      4.1.3 |
| tools              |      4.1.3 |
| utils              |      4.1.3 |
```

Comment: I saw your issue on GitHub and switching off Crayons is a good workaround (but causes still issues with some outputs - can't show you now as I have no Emacs at work :)

The main question remains is why Babel does it correctly with the default session, but fails when a session is specified. Is there no Emacs solution?

Comment: I didn't get any interest from the orgmode list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-03/msg00338.html. I have fixed it locally by over-writing the function from org-mode that is responsible. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The problem is partially fixed with either solution. The issue is that the line 3 in the output is garbled (the line with data types).

Question remains is why it works fine when no session is declared.

Comment: Using session results in the code being evaluated in an interactive comint buffer. Without a session, the code is wrapped in a function with and run with the `--slave` option. This instructs R to "Make R run as quietly as possible", which I guess includes not emitting ANSI codes? The key functions are `org-babel-R-evaluate-external-process` and `org-babel-R-evaluate-session`

Comment: The problem is completely fixed for me with either solution. Maybe try updating all the associated packages: readr, tidyr, crayon?

Comment: With the crayon option, I get no terminal escape codes, but there is extra output: the Column specification block is present in the session evaluation. That is almost certainly an Org mode "feature": the block appears in the session output, so Org mode dutifully prints it out. Maybe there is an option in R to suppress that too?

Comment: @Tyler, I updated the packages and the problem persists (as described by NickD. This is my test org file: https://nest.greenant.net/index.php/s/JxFtTkowHypfRSN (GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.17.4) of 2022-03-12)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Emacs 29. I'll update all my packages and try again, maybe it's a regression?

Comment: @NickD & Peter: I've added the full reproducible example, which I can't reproduce here starting from emacs -Q.

Comment: Thanks for testing @Tyler. I will try to install Emacs 28 tonight (not ready for 29 just yet).

Comment: Hi @Tyler. I have just upgraded to Emacs 28.0.92 and the problem has resolved itself. Thanks for your help.

I think it is still an Org mode bug as it only happens when defining a session. Anyway, I can continue writing my book now.